# Testing 433 MHz Receiver- Data Pin Indicating Constant Signal

Tags: gpio, wireless, radio

I'm trying to understand what's happening with the 443 MHz receiver I've plugged into a Raspberry Pi3. When I plug the data pin into GPIO 21 and I run a simple python sniffer script to plot the results, I get a flat "ON" output after collecting samples for 5 seconds:

[image: Connected]

When I disconnect the data port and I run the sniffer script again, it's clearly not receiving any input:
[image: Disconnected]

Any idea of what could be causing this?

- I don't think I have any interference in the office.
- Other answers suggest that the 5V signal should be converted to 3.3V.
- The ground is connected on the 3.3V side, not sure if that's also a mistake (I'm a software guy, so kinda new to the hardware...)

Here is the tutorial I followed: 
http://www.instructables.com/id/Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-433MHz-Home-Automation/step2/Sniffing-the-handset-codes/

Here is my setup:

- Black Ground
- White 1 - Data
- White 2 - LED (which seems to be always on as well)
- Red - 5V power

[image: Setup01]
[image: Setup02]
[image: Setup03]

Here is the script:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

RECEIVED_SIGNAL = [[], []]  #[[time of reading], [signal reading]]
MAX_DURATION = 5
RECEIVE_PIN = 21

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(RECEIVE_PIN, GPIO.IN)
    cumulative_time = 0
    beginning_time = datetime.now()
    print '**Started recording**'
    while cumulative_time < MAX_DURATION:
        time_delta = datetime.now() - beginning_time
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0].append(time_delta)
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[1].append(GPIO.input(RECEIVE_PIN))
        cumulative_time = time_delta.seconds 
    print '**Ended recording**'
    print len(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0]), 'samples recorded'
    print ('{} seconds recorded'.format(cumulative_time))
    GPIO.cleanup()

    print '**Processing results**'
    for i in range(len(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0])):
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i] = RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i].seconds + RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i].microseconds/1000000.0

    print '**Plotting results**'
    pyplot.plot(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0], RECEIVED_SIGNAL[1])
    pyplot.axis([0, MAX_DURATION, -1, 2])
    pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Are you transmitting a signal?  If you aren't the receiver will be receiving random static and the auto noise thresholding means you will receive a continuous series of highs and lows.  Look at the signal with [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html).

Comment: I tried sending a singal with 433 MHz garage door remote also, but didn't notice any difference. I have a matching RF transmitter which came with the receiver, but I haven't plugged it in yet. I'm trying to eliminate basic errors and get a sanity check first before I try to send signals via the transmitter.

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't look like a flat ON, it seems that it's constantly switched ON and OFF.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Maybe my terminology isn't correct, not sure what's the difference between "flat ON" and "constantly switched ON". I wasn't sure how to properly describe it.

Comment: I didn't write "constantly switched ON", I wrote "constantly switched ON **and OFF**"

Comment: Right, in the first case it is constantly switched ON. In the second case it is constantly switched OFF. But how is the data ping sending out an ON signal? Isn't it supposed to be off until it starts receiving a radio signal and then it sends power through the data pin?

Comment: @Lirik If the diagram showed constant on why isn't is a single thin line at 1 like the single thin line at 0 when off?  The diagram is showing frequent switching between on and off.

Comment: @joan I assumed that it's just how the chart looks (i.e. ON = solid line). However, after re-reading the comments I guess what's happening is indeed a constant ON/OFF. How is that possible?

Comment: @Lirik As explained in my first comment.

Comment: @joan Got it... will look at the signal with piscope first thing tomorrow when I get to the office (I keep my PI @ the office).

Comment: @joan yep, it's the random static.

Comment: @Lirik You can get rid of most of it with the pigs [filter glitch](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#FG) command.  Perhaps try 150 microseconds.

Comment: @joan got it, so it seems that everything is working fine.

Comment: This example automatically applies a filter.  http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D

Comment: @joan Oh, that looks awesome! I'll give it a try.